# What is the 'real-time status text output' data called in ffmpeg and can the columns be customised?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am streaming a static ffmpeg to Twitch for testing a project with something similar to this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/pete/Desktop/2FPS.mp4 -f flv TWITCH_STREAM_ADDRESS
```

When I run it I get the following output in my Ubuntu Terminal pushed to me in real time:

```
frame=   12 fps=0.0 q=22.5 size=      86kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=1912.8kbits/
frame=   27 fps= 27 q=31.0 size=     140kB time=00:00:00.86 bitrate=1316.5kbits/
frame=   42 fps= 28 q=31.0 size=     178kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate=1063.9kbits/
frame=   57 fps= 28 q=31.0 size=     224kB time=00:00:01.87 bitrate= 980.4kbits/
```

I've tried searching, but because the terms 'log' and 'output' are used for different things in ffmpeg I can't seem to find anything where it explains what the name of this 'real-time status text output' data is. What is this data actually called and is it customisable? In other words, can I remove or add on more metadata here - take off size or frame, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what the name of this 'real-time status text output' data

It's called the 'progress stats', or just 'stats'.

> is it customisable

No.

You can control its period using `-stats_period` and send it to a file using `-progress`. You can disable it using `-nostats`.